# Make NSToolbar Icon for NSToolbar

Tags: cocoa, macos, graphics, interface

I'd like to make an icon for my NSToolbar that has the same system stylings applied to it as the template icons in IB.  How do you do this?  I can't get the toolbar to apply system stylings like it says it will in the HIG.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean for a monochromatic icon, make sure you [set it as a template image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setTemplate:). That's what tells the system to render it with the inner gray or blue gradient.

Comment: Could we have more details? In the interface builder, I added a toolbar to my window, added a toolbar item to that, then set its image to a black and transparent image I made with the name "LeftTemplate". It doesn't render with the inner gray gradient. It also doesn't change to any sort of blue when I click on it.

Comment: It is linked to an IBAction, if that makes any difference. Autovalidates is on and Selectable is off. It has a Label and Palette Label. The image is stored in my Images.xcassets folder that Xcode 5 automatically generates.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I think you should ask a separate question.

Comment: I started a new question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852239/toggle-nstoolbaritem-between-black-and-blue

Answer (score 11):

In Mac OS X v10.5 or later, images whose name ends in the word "Template" are automatically marked as template images. [NSImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:)

`NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"MyImageTemplate"];`

This also works for Interface Builder. 
More information: http://www.proppe.org/blog/2007/12/01/nsimage-templates/

Comment: This is a great thing to know! Thanks.

Comment: One caveat: This only works when you get the image from `imageNamed:`. Instantiating an image directly with one of the initializers does not automatically set its template status (or, at least, is not documented as doing so).

Answer (score 2):

The toolbar doesn't do that automatically. You have to create the graphics yourself. The Lion-style icons are usually mid-gray with a subtle inner shadow and a 1px whitish drop shadow. Here's an example done in Photoshop:
[image]

And here's all the layer styling done to it:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The specific numbers and colors may vary depending on the icon's shape and size.

On a side note, the HIG was saying that icons *may* change depending on the control. For example, when you disable a button, its icon will be displayed semi-transparently.